# Hazelcast EC2 - Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, hazelcast

I am trying to deploy a Java Spring application to AWS EC2 with Hazelcast. When the application starts it throws an exception with the following message:

```
Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.
```

My application context is:

```
<bean id="hazelcastInstance" class="com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast" factory-method=" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.hazelcast.config.Config">
            <property name="networkConfig" ref="networkConfig"/>
            <property name="properties">
            <util:properties id="properties">
                <prop key="hazelcast.icmp.enabled">true</prop>
                <prop key="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</prop>
            </util:properties>
        </property>
    </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="networkConfig" class="com.hazelcast.config.NetworkConfig">
    <property name="join" ref="joinConfig"/>
</bean>

<bean id="joinConfig" class="com.hazelcast.config.JoinConfig">
    <property name="awsConfig" ref="awsConfig"/>
    <property name="multicastConfig" ref="multicastConfig"/>
    <property name="tcpIpConfig" ref="tcpIpConfig"/>
</bean>

<bean id="multicastConfig" class="com.hazelcast.config.MulticastConfig">
    <property name="enabled" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tcpIpConfig" class="com.hazelcast.config.TcpIpConfig">
    <property name="enabled" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="awsConfig" class="com.hazelcast.config.AwsConfig">
    <property name="enabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="accessKey" value="{KEY}"/>
    <property name="secretKey" value="{SECRET}"/>
    <!--<property name="region" value="us-east-1"/>-->
</bean>
```

Stacktrace:

```
2016-03-17 22:09:18 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 instance.DefaultAddressPicker] INFO : <> - [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6.1] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
2016-03-17 22:09:18 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 instance.DefaultAddressPicker] INFO : <> - [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6.1] Picked Address[10.43.1.68]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is tru
2016-03-17 22:09:19 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 spi.OperationService] INFO : <> - [10.43.1.68]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Backpressure is disabled
2016-03-17 22:09:19 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 classic.ClassicOperationExecutor] INFO : <> - [10.43.1.68]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Starting with 4 generic operation threads and 8 partition operation threads.
2016-03-17 22:09:19 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 hazelcast.system] INFO : <> - [10.43.1.68]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Hazelcast 3.6.1 (20160228 - d0d2a77) starting at Address[10.43.1.68]:5701
2016-03-17 22:09:19 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 hazelcast.system] INFO : <> - [10.43.1.68]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2016-03-17 22:09:19 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 hazelcast.system] INFO : <> - [10.43.1.68]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2016-03-17 22:09:19 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 instance.Node] INFO : <> - [10.43.1.68]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Creating AWSJoiner
2016-03-17 22:09:19 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 core.LifecycleService] INFO : <> - [10.43.1.68]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Address[10.43.1.68]:5701 is STARTING
2016-03-17 22:09:19 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 nonblocking.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel] INFO : <> - [10.43.1.68]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
2016-03-17 22:09:19 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 impl.TcpIpJoinerOverAWS] WARN : <> - [10.43.1.68]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHello(ClientHandshaker.java:448)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:202)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
```

... full stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/sWK89fQK

Application is java 8 application deployed into Tomcat 8. Why may this be the case?

Comment: Did you configure ssl in hazelcast? or ec2 machine?

Comment: @bilal I tried configuring ssl in the application and that didn't work. I debugged through the AwsJoiner class and could see the http url that it was calling on the ec2 AWS API and calling that from postman worked and returned data about my ec2 instances. However for some reason it believed the SSL configuration was not correct

Comment: i want to reproduce your case, so i have to configure ssl and should try aws discovery? right?